# PHP 5.5's (MS) SQL server functions not working as expected

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, php-5.5

My sys admin is upgrading my PHP server from 5.2 to 5.5 . As a result, the mssql family of functions is gone and I have to update my code (it seems to either the odbc functions or sqlsrv functions). Unfortunately, neither seems to be working correctly for anything beyond simple queries.

I've reduced one of the problematic queries down to the following two variants (middle line added is the only change):

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#i') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #i END
SELECT 'value' as test

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#i') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #i END
CREATE TABLE #i (id INT primary key) INSERT INTO #i SELECT 405782
SELECT 'value' as test
```

When I try them in SQL Server Mangement Studio, both work fine and return one row. When I try the first one from PHP, it works fine and returns one row. However, when I try to execute the second query from PHP I get an unexpected result:

```php
$SQL_query= '********'; //Second query
$serverName = '**********';
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"*****","UID"=>"********","PWD"=>"*********");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$msg1=sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL); // ""

if($conn){ //truthy
  $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$SQL_query);
  if(sqlsrv_has_rows ($result)){$rows='true';}else{$rows='false';} //false
  $msg2=sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL); // ""
  $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) //false
}
```

(The odbc functions were even worse, choking if the query contained a SET @var statement...)

So the result of the query is incorrect, but no errors are reported.

Can anyone explain this? You'd think if the range of queries that could be handled by these functions was somehow limited that it would be at least mentioned in passing in the PHP documentation for these functions.

For reference: Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition 9.00.1406.00, PHP 5.5.19  x86 thread safety disabled, running on Windows.

Edit: Per Rob Farley's suggestion, I've confirmed that the @@OPTIONS are either identical or immaterial to reproducing the problem.

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON;` did the trick! If you make your comment into an answer, I'll give you the bounty

Comment: Done -- now please review the answer to see if it's correct, or if another `SET NOCOUNT OFF` was necessary.

Comment: For my example query, I did not need to set it back OFF. If I find that I need to do so for my larger result set, I'll make a followup comment.

Comment: If this particular query is working throughout with `SET NOCOUNT ON`, it's very probable that the code can't handle rowcounts on multi-statement batches, and thus requires `NOCOUNT ON` throughout. The only exception would be if you actually use the rowcount somewhere, of course (with `sqlserv_num_rows`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the client framework is confused by the row counts that are returned by default for every statement. When the first `INSERT` happens, it returns a row count of 1, making it appear as if this is a statement returning results, which it's not -- the row count may even get confused for the result itself. PHP isn't the only technology troubled by this; jTDS is another driver that has trouble (in the case of jTDS, it *requires* the row count). `SET NOCOUNT ON` suppresses this extra information:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#i') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #i END
CREATE TABLE #i (id INT primary key)
INSERT INTO #i SELECT 405782
SELECT 'value' as test
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what driver you're using (freetds?), you could be finding that `ANSI_NULLS` (and other ANSI settings, such as `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`) are set differently to what is expected, and this can affect things such as the creation of tables. Try passing in a query that tests those values, and you will quite probably find the problem.

Comment: I had used 3.1 (Preview) from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx . Now that there was an update on Friday  and it no longer says Preview, I'll try updating it. Can you provide any pointer/reference to what values I should be querying to test?

Comment: These: SET ARITHABORT ON  SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  SET ANSI_NULLS ON  SET ANSI_PADDING ON  SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON  SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

Comment: I checked all the @@OPTIONS bits and they were the same between SQL Server Managements studio, and the sqlsrv call from PHP (and matching your setting above), with the exception of ARITHABORT being off for PHP. Setting the PHP option to that of SSMS (ON) did not cause the problematic query to succeed in PHP. Setting the SSMS option to that of PHP (OFF) did not cause the problematic query to fail is SSMS.